# manipulation of text by sed command

Tags: sed

I a file containing the genome ids following NZ_FLAT01000030.1_173 I need to manipulate those ids like this one: NZ_FLAT01000030.1
I tried some but didn't give me the exact thing.

```
sed 's/_/\t/' output : NZ FLAT01000030.1_173
sed -r 's/_//' output: NZFLAT01000030.1_173
sed -r 's/_//g' output: NZFLAT01000030.1173
```

How can I do that by using sed command?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to remove the undesrscore and the digits following it?

```
echo 'NZ_FLAT01000030.1_173' | sed -E 's/_[0-9]+//g'

NZ_FLAT01000030.1
```

Comment: I tried but it removed all underscore while I need the first one. I need to remove second one with digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'NZ_FLAT01000030.1_173' | sed 's/_[^_]*$//'
NZ_FLAT01000030.1
```